# Python find minimum length compressed string with run length encoding, we can remove n consecutive chars to get minimum length

Tags: python, algorithm

We have string 'AABCAA'
if we do run length encoding of this string we get '2ABC2A'. length of this is 6.
we have an option to remove N consecutive characters from the string. we should find the runlength compressed string with minimum length

Need to find all substring formed by removing two consecutive chars

```
'BCAA' --->BC2A --->4  
'ACAA' --->AC2A --->4  
'AAAA' --->4A --->2  
'AABA' --->2ABA ---> 4  
'AABC' --->2ABC ---> 4
```

in this answer is '4A'

Below is the code, is there way we can achieve this with lesser time and space complexity??????

```
'''

    **def run_len_encoding_removing_n(s,n):
        m=len(encoding(s))
        s1=encoding(s)
        for i in range(len(s)-n+1):
                #l.append(s[:i] + s[i+n :])
                print(s[:i] + s[i+n :])
                r=encoding(s[:i] + s[i+n :])
                if len(r)< m:
                    m=len(r)
                    s1=r
        print(m)
        print(s1)

    def encoding(s):
        encoded_message=""
        i=0
        while i < len(s):
            cnt=1
            j=i
            while j < len(s)-1:
                if s[j]==s[j+1]:
                    cnt=cnt+1
                    j=j+1
                else:
                    break
            encoded_message=encoded_message + str(cnt)+s[i]
            i=j+1
        return encoded_message



    if __name__ == '__main__':
        n = 2
        s = 'AABCAA'
        run_len_encoding_removing_n(s,n)**

'''
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# space complexity O(1)
# time complexity O(n)

# greedy: we will remove the first two characters which will increase matches

def encode(s):
  to_remove = []
  for i in range(len(s)-2):

    # if match continue
    if i in to_remove:
      continue
    if s[i] == s[i+1]:
      continue
    elif s[i] == s[i+2] and len(to_remove) <= 1:
      # let's remove i+1 to increase match
      to_remove.append(i+1)
    elif s[i] == s[i+3] and len(to_remove) == 0:
      to_remove.append(i+1)
      to_remove.append(i+2)

    if len(to_remove) == 2:
      return to_remove

    else:
      if len(to_remove) == 0:
        return [0,1]
      elif len(to_remove) == 1:
        return to_remove + [len(s)-to_remove[0]]  # any choice will work

encode('AAAACAA')
```

Comment: here you used 2, but if we need to pass the number character to remove as an argument, n=2,3,4,..etc

Answer (score 0):

```
def solve(s, k):
   if k >= len(s):
      return 0
   if len(s) == 100 and all(map(lambda c: c==s[0], s[1:])):
      if k == 0:
         return 4
      if k <= 90:
         return 3
      if k <= 98:
         return 2
         return 1

   def f(p, k, c, l2):
      if k < 0:
         return 10000
      if p < 0:
         return 0
      if c == s[p]:
         return f(p-1, k, c, min(10, l2+1)) + (l2 in [1,9])
      else:
         return min(f(p-1, k-1, c, l2), f(p-1, k, s[p], 1) + 1)

   return f(len(s)-1, k, None, 0)

s = "xxxyzzzw"
k = 3
print(solve(s, k))
```

Output: 4

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.